# Ruby string range

Tags: ruby, string

How can i check in ruby length of string, it's range, something like:

```
s_query.length?[5..20]
```

I'm new to ruby, how to code such code, for if check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it:

```
 (5..20).cover? s_query.length
```

Answer (score 5):

check this

```
s_query.length.between?(5, 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also
`s_query.length.between?(5,20)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to meditate on:

```
(5 .. 10) === 'hello world'.length # => false
(5 .. 10) === 'foo bar'.length # => true
```

This works because [`===`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) is defined in Range to return a Boolean true/false whether the right side is within the left-side range.

From [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D):

> rng === obj → true or false click to toggle source
>
> Returns true if obj is an element of the range, false otherwise. Conveniently, === is the comparison operator used by case statements.

```
case 79
when 1..50   then   print "low\n"
when 51..75  then   print "medium\n"
when 76..100 then   print "high\n"
end
```

> produces:

```
high
```